# Where the view rendering logic belongs to, functions.php or content-partial template?

Tags: php, wordpress, refactoring

I am implementing a "Recently Post" rendering logic with Wordpress recently. Based on @helenhousandi's [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26482/grab-5-latest-posts-from-custom-post-type-announcements), I did the task through `WP_Query()` to pull out my posts.

However, I am facing a architecture issue right now. In Wordpress, there are 3 ways to include this loop rendering snippets inside a `single.php` file:

---

### 1. Put the rendering logic directly in `single.php`

#### single.php

```
<div id="header-announcements">
<h3>Announcements</h3>
    <?php
    $queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=announcements&posts_per_page=5' );
    // The Loop!
    if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
        while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
            $queryObject->the_post();
            ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
        <div><a href="#">View More</a></div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is the easiest way, but hard to reuse for other custom post type.

---

### 2. Using `get_template_url()` to include the loop rendering logic

#### conctent-recently-post.php

```
<?php
$queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=announcements&posts_per_page=5' );
// The Loop!
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        $queryObject->the_post();
        ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <div><a href="#">View More</a></div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

#### single.php

```
<div id="header-announcements">
<h3>Announcements</h3>
    <?php get_template_url( 'content', 'recently-post'); ?>
</div>
```

Put the rendering logic in a separate template file, say `content-recently-post.php`, and then include that in `single.php`. This should be better, since it could be reused in other template files.

What fall short here is that, the `post_type` and `posts_per_page` are tightly coupled with the rendering logic, so it's still hard to reuse.

---

### 3. Register a function in `functions.php`, and call the function in `single.php`

#### functions.php

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('ka_show_recently_post')) :
    function ka_show_recently_post($post_type, $num) {
      $queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=' . $post_type . '&posts_per_page=' . $num );
      if ($queryObject->have_posts()) :
          echo '<ul>';
          while ($queryObject->have_posts()) :
              $queryObject->the_post();
              echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
          endwhile;
          echo '</ul>';
      endif;
    }
endif;
?>
```

#### single.php

```
<div id="header-announcements">
<h3>Announcements</h3>
    <?php ka_show_recently_post('announcements', 5) ?>
</div>
```

The good part for this approach is that it allows you to reuse it according to the `post_type` and `posts_per_page` that you would like to, but I think it's a little weird to put these kinds of rendering logic in `functions.php`. We should put all these template relating logic in separate template files, which forms a better structure for future maintenance, shouldn't we?

> **I am wondering is there any other better ways to solve the rendering
>   logic in Wordpress like that in this example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine 2&3.

Use a function that accepts $posttype as an argument.

Extract the template part to a template file
and include the template file in the function.